# Why I am still able to see analytics data in my Google Analytics dashboard?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, report

Google is sunsetting Google Analytics support from [February, 2020](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112).

> After our service is fully turned down in February 2020, these legacy properties will no longer be accessible via the Google Analytics UI or API, and the **associated data will be deleted** from Google Analytics servers. In advance of this turndown, **we recommend that you export the data** so you can retrieve it later.

**I wonder why I am still able to see analytics data in my Google Analytics dashboard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is still obtainable from API (just tried):

[image]

Anyway anyway at the end of the link you entered it says:

> This lead time of 12 months, beginning November 2018, was extended to you so you could make the transition to tracking your apps with the Firebase SDKs.

Therefore it may be unclear written documentation, in any case the migration process is inevitable considering that now Google are focusing everything on Google Analytics 4 with the aim of making it the reference system in the next 3 or 4 years.